# Artinian topological space are compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Call a topological space $X$ *Artinian* if every nested sequence of closed sets

$$C_1 \supset C_2 \supset C_3 \supset \cdots$$

is eventually constant.

> Prove that if $X$ is *Artinian* then it is also compact.

I don't have a concrete strategy for attacking this. I am assuming (maybe wrongly so) that appealing to the finite intersection property might be of some help. Is this the case? Should I employ a different strategy?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: There exists some relation between noetherian and artinian topological spaces as in the case of rings and modules? Sorry for this question here.

Comment: This is weird terminology. Don't most people call this property of a topological space being Noetherian?

Comment: Indeed, this space is Noetherian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take an open cover $\{U_i\mid i\in I\}$. Using the axiom of choice we can assume that $I$ is well-ordered and so we can write $V_i=\bigcup_{j<i}U_i$, then $\{V_i\mid i\in I\}$ is an open cover as well.

Use the usual trick of complements and the Artinian property to conclude there is a finite subcover, or else.

Comment: ...or else what? ;)

Comment: @Daniel: Or else $0=1$, that's what! :-)